# Creating Single sided buffer with Virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, virtual-layer

I'm creating a layer with single sided buffers based on a line layer as virtual layer in QGIS with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    ST_SingleSidedBuffer(layer.geometry, layer.buffer_dist, layer.side) 
FROM
    layer;
```

The buffer distance and the buffer side for each feature ist stored in the attribute table.

I would like to the set the join style to `'MITRE'`. I found that there should be a way to set the option like this (https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=BufferOptions):

```sql
SELECT BufferOptions_SetJoinStyle('MITRE');
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such
> function: BufferOptions_SetJoinStyle

Hence my question: Is there a way to set the buffer options globally in the QGIS project? Or is there a way to set the buffer options within the query?

Comment: As stated in your link, this feature set is available with *SpatiaLite* 5.0 and above. I believe even at version 3.20 QGIS is built with *SpatiaLite* 4.3.0a by default, so you do not have access to that feature set within the native QGIS environment.

Answer (score 1):

As it does not seem to be possible right now using a virtual layer (as stated in the comment by @geozelot), you might want to use another method to achieve the same result. You can use QGIS expressions with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) (for visualization only) or `Menu processing / Toolbox / [Geometry by expression`][2](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) to create actual geometries (see [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

Use the function [single_sided_buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#single-sided-buffer), it has the following syntax:

```
single_sided_buffer(geometry,distance[,segments=8][,join=1][,miter_limit=2.0])
```

Help says:

> join - join style for corners, where 1 = round, 2 = miter and 3 =
> bevel

The whole expression thus looks something like (change the fieldnames   `"buffer_dist"` and `buffer_side`):

```
single_sided_buffer(
    $geometry, 
    "buffer_dist" * "buffer_side",
    join:=2
)
```

*The expression, here with Geometry genrator - initial line in red, buffers in blue:*
[image]

Comment: This topic is about a Virtual Layer, not *Geometry by expression*, *Geometry generator* etc. :)

Comment: Yes, I know :-) But as someone commented, it seems not to be possible with virtual layer - so this is probably the closest way to achieve the result. Sometimes a question is not so much about a particular *method* how to achieve someting, but simply to draw the OP to other possibilities how to achieve the same *result*.

Comment: Thanks @Babel for your input! I appreciate your out of the box thinking :) The reason I'm using a virtual layer here is that I need the buffer layer to be dynamically and I also want to be able to export the geometries to a file (so I need the actual geometries). I also created a spatial model which is generating a buffer layer, but this solution is not dynamically. And as far as I know _Geometry by expression_ is also not dynamically.

Comment: `Geomtry generator` is dynamic, but does not create actual geometries. `Geomtry by expression` creates actual geometries, but is not dynamic. But combining both (depending on your workflow) could solve the problem. You say you want to export the geometries to a file: this will not be dynamic, either, and is exactly what Geomerty by expression does.